,Getting error:- ValueError: Input nan is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers
I tried to run Bert+bilstm+crf model for NER. Iam getting error as ValueError: Input nan is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers.
best_loss = np.inf
for epoch in range(config.EPOCHS):
    train_loss = train_fn(
        train_data_loader, 
        model, 
        optimizer, 
        device, 
        scheduler
    )
 test_loss = eval_fn(
        valid_data_loader,
        model,
        device
    )
    print(f"Train Loss = {train_loss} Valid Loss = {test_loss}")
    if test_loss < best_loss:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), config.MODEL_PATH)
        best_loss = test_loss

On 3rd line i am getting error as ValueError: Input nan is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers.
Any suggestions how to solve this?. Actually I am new in this field...
